# Descartar, o no una fila según el valor de una columna específica

Tags: sql-server, sql

Buen día, ando peleando con una query en sql (sql-server), tengo la siguiente tabla.

```
ValueText   nvarchar(MAX)   Unchecked
RevisionNo  int Unchecked
ProjectID   int Unchecked
DocumentID  int Unchecked
VariableID  int Unchecked
```

Donde, `RevisionNo`, `ProjectID`, `DocumentID` y `VariableID` son claves primarias.

`RevisionNo`, hace referencia a la revisión actual de un documento (`DocumentID`), lo que yo intento, es obtener el valor de `ValueText`, para cada `DocumentID`, pero únicamente, traer el de la última revisión disponible en cada caso.

Por ejemplo, haciendo un select sin modificaciones

```
SELECT  DocumentId, VariableID, RevisionNo ,ValueText
    FROM [PDMWE_ARTRANS].[dbo].[VariableValue]
    WHERE DocumentID = 91474
```

Obtendría el siguiente resultado

```
DocumentId  VariableID  RevisionNo  ValueText
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------
91474       150         6           27/06/19
91474       238         2           Catálogo
91474       238         4           CATÁLOGO TÉCNICO
91474       265         3           EN EDICIÓN
91474       265         5           ESP. REVISIÓN
91474       265         7           ESP. APROBACIÓN
91474       265         9           APROBADO
91474       304         6           W.W
91474       351         2           CONMUTADOR BAJO CARGA
```

Donde como se puede ver, para la misma VariableID tengo, en algunos casos, varios resultados.

Lo que pretendería obtener, sería lo siguiente:

```
DocumentId  VariableID  RevisionNo  ValueText
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------
91474       150         6           27/06/19
91474       238         4           CATÁLOGO TÉCNICO
91474       265         9           APROBADO
91474       304         6           W.W
91474       351         2           CONMUTADOR BAJO CARGA
```

En caso, de que exista la misma variable con más de una revisión, que la query devuelva la fila que tiene la revisión mayor.

Lo intenté usando GroupBy y Having

```
SELECT  DocumentId, VariableID, RevisionNo ,max(ValueText) as 'ValueText'
    FROM [PDMWE_ARTRANS].[dbo].[VariableValue]
    WHERE DocumentID = 91474    
        GROUP BY ProjectID ,DocumentId, VariableID, RevisionNo
            HAVING RevisionNo = max(RevisionNo)
```

Pero no tuve éxito.

¿Cómo debería encarar este problema?

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: El problema me fue un poco complicado de explicar, si no se interpreta bien, intento redactarlo de otra manera!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT t1.DocumentId, t1.VariableID, t1.RevisionNo, t1.ValueText
FROM VariableValue t1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT DocumentId, VariableID, MAX(RevisionNo) AS RevisionNo 
    FROM VariableValue GROUP BY ProjectID, DocumentId, VariableID) t2 
ON t1.DocumentId = t2.DocumentId AND t1.VariableID = t2.VariableID 
AND t1.RevisionNo = t2.RevisionNo
WHERE t1.DocumentID = 91474
```

De esta manera obtienes sólo la línea con el número de revisión más alta por cada Documento, Variable y Proyecto diferente.

Lo que hace la consulta es obtener los datos `DocumentId, VariableID, RevisionNo, ValueText` filtrados por la consulta `DISTINCT` que adjunto con el `INNER JOIN`.

Aquí te dejo el Fiddle donde he hecho las pruebas: [Enlace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04e26/25)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Llevaba mucho rato peleando con esto!